# Error Installation Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

While following the installation steps for "Mac OS X" [Installation and Quick Start](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/)

I used the below command:-

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

and directory extract under  `/Users/xxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/`

but I got this error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/xxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 8, in <module>
import bootstrapping
File "/Users/xxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 9, in <module>
import setup
File "/Users/xxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py", line 44, in <module>
from googlecloudsdk.core.util import platforms
File "/Users/xxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/../../lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/platforms.py", line 6, in <module>
import platform
ImportError: No module named platform
```

**Environment:-**

- Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10
- Python 2.7.6
- $ whereis python `/usr/bin/python`

Can someone help?

Comment: [platform](https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html) is a standard Python module. If it's not there, your Python installation is corrupted.

Comment: Maybe you should re-install  your Python, then try to install the Cloud SDK one more time.

Comment: platform module is there, `>>> import platform
>>> platform.__file__
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform.pyc'`

Comment: Mac os x Yosemite comes already with python, but I have installed python via `brew` to avoid this issue, unfortunately, nothing.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, would you open a new issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list and include the output of `$ gcloud info` in your issue?  We haven't seen this before, and it's difficult to reproduce because platform should be picked up from the stdlib.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, you probably won't be able to run `gcloud info`... instead, please try debugging the environment variables in the "answer" below, and add any relevant info to the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found different locations of standard modules, for example:-

- `>>> import platform >>> platform.__file__` => `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/platform‌​.pyc'`
- `>>> import os >>> os.__file__` => somewhere inside my profile `/Users/xxxxx/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/...` ,

So, I have solved this issue by following steps:-

- removed `/Users/xxxxx/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/`.
- reinstalled python through `brew` to keep Apple python away.

then, Google Cloud SDK was installed smoothly and is working properly.

and the new location of standard modules is `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/`

Comment: I did not even have to delete it. I just ran `brew install python@2`.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment since i don't have enough rep, so posting as an "answer".

As others have commented, platform is a standard module. It should be there barring a bad python installation.
Since the python in PATH seems to import platform correctly, maybe Cloud SDK is using a different python.

Check if the environment variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON is set. That usually tells gcloud to use a different python.

You can also change `/Users/xxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud` and right before the last line, echo the bash variables $CLOUDSDK_PYTHON, $CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_ARGS, $CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR, and $PYTHONPATH. This should tell us if something is configured badly with the python that gcloud uses.

Answer (score 1):

on linux i fixed this by running install.py directly .you can apply the same on mac os i guess,
go to the folder where you have extracted google cloud sdk then,

```
 cd /bin/bootstrapping
```

there you will find install.py ,run it using

```
./install.py
```

then installation begins and proceed with the steps .After that open a new terminal gcloud works!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue with a different system package (contextlib), solved it by setting the environment parameter: CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1 before installing.